# How to make dialog to look like ICS theme

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-dialog

from service i'm creating a dialog via a dummy activity. Here i'm able to see black background, overall the theme of dialog looks like Android V 2.2. My application minimum API level is 8, if i use holo theme it says i need min api level as 14.

Here is the code i used to create dialog. How to get ICS theme dialog.

```
  public class PreviewDialog extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Show the popup dialog
        showDialog(0);


    }



@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    super.onCreateDialog(id);

    // Build the dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("ALARM REMINDER");
    alert.setMessage("Its time for the alarm ");
    alert.setCancelable(false);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            GoogleTaskPreviewDialog.this.finish();
        }
    });

    // Create and return the dialog
    AlertDialog dlg = alert.create();

    return dlg;
}
}
```

MY manifest file entry

```
 <activity android:name="PreviewDialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not really use the theme from `HOLO` that it is design only for `api >= 14/ice cream sandwich`

**solution:**

You can either design your own dialog layout that will look like a dialog from `HOLO theme` or check if the current device's API is greater than or equal to `ice cream sandwich` and set the `HOLO theme` for dialog if it is else just use the dialog theme from 2.2.

**sample:**

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alert;
        // Build the dialog
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
        else
            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Also take note that `onCreateDialog` is deprecated, I would recommend using just the instance object of the `AlertDialog` for showing the dialog instead of creating it inside the `onCreateDialog` and showing it by calling `showDialog`.

Comment: In oncreate method itself i can create dialog right?

Comment: Ok, thanks. do you have any sample theme which looks like ics holo dialog for android v2.2, i tried lot, i'm using actionbarsherlock here also standard ics them of dialogs are depricated :(,

Comment: @Naruto Sorry I really dont have the theme, but you can just create the layout in your IDE.

Comment: @Naruto no probs, happy coding. :))

Answer (score 0):

Your can use AlertDialogPro to build a Holo theme dialog across all versions of Android.

https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro